# File commit date in JGit

Tags: java, git, jgit

Is it possible to resolve the date and time when a certain file was committed for the first time using JGit?

Git equivalent would be listing the first commit, like:

```
git log --format=%aD <FILE> | tail -1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `RevWalk` can be used as follows to obtain the first commit that contains 'file.txt'

```
RevWalk revWalk = new RevWalk( repository );
revWalk.markStart( revWalk.parseCommit( repository.resolve( Constants.HEAD ) ) );
revWalk.setTreeFilter( PathFilter.create( "path/to/file.txt" ) );
revWalk.sort( RevSort.COMMIT_TIME_DESC );
revWalk.sort( RevSort.REVERSE, true );
RevCommit commit = revWalk.next();
...
revWalk.dispose();
```

In the example the history starts at `HEAD`. Adjust the `markStart()` call the start from somewhere else or call `markStart()` multiple times to include several start points.

The `PathFilter` excludes commits that do not contain the given repository-relative path name. And finally the two `sort()` calls take care that commits are ordered by their time stamp (newest first) in reverse order. Hence the oldest commit that contains the given file is returned by `next()`.

Be aware that the commit passed to `markStart()` must be from the same revision walker, i.e. it must be obtained with a call to `parseCommit()` from the same revWalk instance. See also [this thread](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jgit-dev/msg02247.html) for more details.

Comment: It seems that "file.txt" is not enough but also the path has to be mentioned starting from the Repo's root folder (for example if the file is located at <repo>/src/file.txt, the path is "src/file.txt." After that, adding commit.getCommitTime() did the trick. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Of course, the full (repository-relative) path needs to be specified. Thanks for pointing that out. I have clarified the answer.